# Undefined local variable or method `params' - In Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

**Story:**

It goes something like, when a user hits a 'like' button on user's post it sends the post owner a notification. The route for each posts look like `/users/:user_id/posts/:id`

**Assumption: SendGrid is configured and working ok.**

**Generating the post notification:**

`rails g mailer PostNotification`

**In app/mailers/post_notification.rb:**

```
class PostNotification < ActionMailer::Base

  default :from => 'no-reply@example.com'

  def send_notification_email(user)
    user = User.friendly.find( params[:user_id] ) # params only work in the views/controller. How to get it to work here??
    mail( :to => user.email, # should send to that particular post owner
    :subject => "You've got a post like" )
  end
end
```

**app/views/post_notification/send_notification_email.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>You've got a new like from, <%= current_user.name %>!</h1>
     <p>Blaahhhhhh</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app/controller/posts_controller:**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def like
   [...] # other working code
   if p.save
    PostNotification.send_notification_email(@user).deliver
  end

end
```

The idea is to grab the `user_id` for that post so that the notification/email goes to that user, with a message, in the body, from the (current_user). The trouble Im having is in the `post_notification.rb`. How to grab the user_id for that 'post owner' so the email goes to them?

Comment: I guess `params` can't be used in `Mailer`

Comment: Joking? I may have to create a hack for this as I dont see any other way.

Comment: Why would you have to hack anything? You're already passing a user object. Just use user.id to get the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***ActionMailer*** does not have access to the controller `params`, so you can't access `params` hash inside your mailer.

You can pass the params you need as arguments instead like you passed the `user` in the argument in your `send_notification_email` method. Use that user's id if you need:

```
def send_notification_email(user)
  user = User.friendly.find(user.id) # use the id of the passed user
  mail( :to => user.email,
        :subject => "You've got a post like" )
end
```

Apparently, you can even omit `user = User.friendly.find(user.id) # use the id of the passed user` line because you already have the `user` object which you can directly use in the `mail` method call:

```
def send_notification_email(user)
  mail(:to => user.email,
        :subject => "You've got a post like")
end
```

Both of these should work. And the bottom line is: ***ActionMailer*** does not have access to the controller `params` hash which is the cause of your error. :-)

Comment: Your answer has the much clear explanation than mine.

Comment: Thanks but Im now getting `undefined method email for nil:NilClass`

Comment: This is because, your `user` is `nil`. How are you passing the `user` to this method? From a controller? Make sure you send the `user` from there properly.

Comment: yeah, so make sure that you actually have `user` present before you call `send_notification_email(use)` method. Then, it will work :) You can do a: `puts #{user.inspect}` in your controller to see if you are getting the `user` properly or not.

Comment: Im having a warm time getting that user. If I hard code to `user = User.find(2)` it works but not with the `User.find(user.id)`

Comment: That should be something like this (in your controller): `User.find(params[:id])` or `User.find(params[:user_id])` depending how you receive the `user_id` in your `params` hash in your controller. Try to inspect the `params` hash in the controller method: `puts params: #{params.inspect}` and see how you get `user_id`, based on that, grab the user id like this: `params[:id]` or `params[:user_id]` and then use that to find the user from the database: `User.find(params[:id])` or `User.find(params[:user_id])`

Comment: I should be calling the Post Controller instead lol. You guys answer work it was my mistake of calling the User Controller.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this line `user = User.friendly.find( params[:user_id] )` actually. You are passing `@user` as an argument here `send_notification_email(@user)`, so it is accessed as `user` in the `mailer method`. The below should work.

```
class PostNotification < ActionMailer::Base

  default :from => 'no-reply@example.com'

  def send_notification_email(user)
    mail( :to => user.email, :subject => "You've got a post like" )
  end
end
```